# JavaScript module pattern function or jQuery delegate

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'd loike to know which solutions better to use module pattern or write a handle function for an input element action?

```
<button type="button" onClick="main.update.buttonClick">Click</button>

(function($) { 
 'use strict'; 
 window.main.update = window.main.update || ();

 main.update.init = function() { ... };

 main.update.buttonClick = function() { ... }; })(jQuery);
```

or

```
 <button id="update" type="button">Click</button>

(function($) { 
 'use strict'; 
 window.main.update = window.main.update || ();

 main.update.init = function() { 
  $("#update").on("click", functio() { ... });
 };
```

What is the better solution or there is another more better one, please?

Answer (score 1):

I prefere a pattern like this...

```
'use strict';

 (function ($) {

    function doStuffHere() {
        // Do stuff here
    }

    function init() {
        $(window).on('whatever', function () {
            // Trigger the above on what you want and call function
            function doStuffHere();
         }
    }

    // This shorthand for call function init() on dom ready
    $(init);

 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.